# Нужна помощь со вложенным запросом Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

структура и данные таблицы тут https://pastebin.com/u1GY7gvr

запрос вида

```
SELECT login, subs_id, ip, login_out 
FROM cam.test 
WHERE subs_id IN (SELECT subs_id 
                  FROM cam.test 
                  GROUP BY subs_id 
                  HAVING COUNT(id) > 1);
```

на что получаю

```
login      |subs_id|ip            |login_out |
-----------|-------|--------------|----------|
baka       |     90|0.0.0.0       |         0|
baka2      |     90|92.24.19.31   |1578325414|
aniko1     |    143|76.18.113.22  |1578325421|
aniko2     |    143|111.195.16.161|1578325422|
```

Но мне нужно еще перед запросом отсеять те значения login_out, которые

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - login_out) < 30
```

Тоесть в итоге я должен получить

```
login      |subs_id|ip            |login_out |
-----------|-------|--------------|----------|
aniko1     |    143|76.18.113.22  |1578325421|
aniko2     |    143|111.195.16.161|1578325422|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение такое:

```
SELECT login, subs_id, ip, login_out 
FROM cam.test 
WHERE subs_id IN (SELECT subs_id 
                  FROM cam.test 
                  where (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - login_out) < 30
                  GROUP BY subs_id 
                  HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
                  )
and login_out > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так и запишите то что вам нужно

```
SELECT 
  login, 
  subs_id, 
  ip, 
  login_out 
FROM 
  cam.test 
WHERE 
  subs_id IN (SELECT subs_id FROM cam.test GROUP BY subs_id HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) 
  and (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - login_out) < 30;
```

Либо, если я неверно понял условие, вариант 2:

```
SELECT 
  login, 
  subs_id, 
  ip, 
  login_out 
FROM 
  cam.test 
WHERE 
  subs_id IN (
    SELECT 
      subs_id 
    FROM 
      cam.test 
    WHERE 
      (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - login_out) < 30
    GROUP BY subs_id 
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
  );
```

Comment: к сожалению я получаю в выхлопе login_out c нулем, что неправильно
```
login       |subs_id|ip            |login_out |
------------|-------|--------------|----------|
aniko1     |    143|16.1.43.22    |1578327961|
aniko2     |    143|1.15.156.131|1578327962|
aniko3     |    143|0.0.0.0          |                  0|
```

Comment: @ryan88 На второй запрос - вполне возможно, на первый - крайне странно =)
Поправил код(ситуацию изменить не должно, но попробуйте теперь)

Comment: эту ошибку я сам увидел и конечно она ничего не изменила)

Comment: Залейте куда либо данных для теста, попробую исправить запрос(но пока с трудом верю что первый запрос возвращает строки с нулем)

Comment: первый запрос возвращает строки subs_id в количестве меньше 2

Comment: @ryan88 *к сожалению я получаю в выхлопе login_out c нулем, что неправильно* A у вас точно в таблице есть записи со штампом времени в пределах 30 секунд от момента выполнения запроса?

Comment: @Akina а разве будет вообще вывод если таковых нет? имхо должен вернутся пустой ответ если таковых нету(в первом запросе)

Comment: конечно, обновление данных таблицы происходит каждые 10 секунд

Comment: @ryan88 Добавьте в список вывода `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` и `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - login_out` - и смотрите, что собственно косячит и как.

Comment: @ryan88 И вот ещё... А какой тип данных у поля `login_out` ? Если TIMESTAMP - то какая зона времени к нему применяется? Не отвечайте, не проверив...

Comment: А какой тип данных у поля login_out ?  Integer

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Залил сюда https://pastebin.com/u1GY7gvr